# Using curly braces just for code folding?

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I am currently teaching myself JavaScript.

When I am dealing with a single text file that starts getting long and hard to navigate, I usually use full lines of slashes to make comment headers for each section. I realized that if I just enclosed a section of code in curly braces (i.e., { long section of code } that my text editor (brackets) will allow me to just fold the entire section. While this does make my life much easier, I wonder if this is going to create any complications regarding scope or anything or if the brackets, not being attached to any labels, don't actually create any behavior other than allowing my text editor to fold the section.

Comment: `When I am dealing with a single text file that starts getting long and hard to navigate` that's when you refactor your code. Move the parts that belong together into a separate file.

Comment: Many IDEs allow you to use "regions" (or have plugins that add the functionality). For instance, VSCode allows me to add a comment like `// #region Blah` with a corresponding `// #endregion Blah` and allows me to fold that away. However, I agree with @Olian04 that if your file is getting that unwieldy, consider refactoring to include more modules/classes/whatever to ensure composability.

Comment: 'long and hard to navigate' right now is less than 50 lines. I just want to be able to fold sections with a couple related functions or with a class and its functions. the regions idea is exactly what I want, I'll see if theres a plugin for that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, inserting curly braces may cause bugs or compilation errors with existing code, because curly braces define a lexical scope.  You may end up unintentionally hiding a variable that is used after the block you created, or shadowing one that was defined before the block.

There are use cases for creating these lexical blocks in the middle of code, however, it is not only for organization purposes.  To that end, it is better to extract your chunk of code to a separate function/class/module/file/etc if you're looking to organize. The benefits of doing this are vast.

It is interesting to note, however, that some languages+IDE's support features solely for the use-case you describe.  For example, C# has [#region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region), which delimits a collapsible section of code.

Also, I would say most IDE's already support collapsing/expanding certain code constructs (like function/method bodies) out-of-the-box, so you might get that behaviour for free you refactor your code a bit.